# Riesz representation theorem for $C(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm dealing with the Riesz representation theorem to prove that the dual $C(\mathbb{T})^*$ is (isometric to) the space of complex Borel measures on $\mathbb{T}$.
On the other hand I've read that the Riesz representation theorem establishes a correspondence with *regular* complex Borel measures on $\mathbb{T}$.

My question is: in my case with $\mathbb{T}$ the correspondence is with complex Borel measures or with regular complex Borel measures? Or it turns out that they are the same in the space $\mathbb{T}$?.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All Borel measures on a compact metric space are regular.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks u!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments: "All Borel measures on a compact metric space are regular."